# Shell script running commands creates more than one processes

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following bash script:

```
COMMAND="python myservice.py start"
su root -c "$COMMAND" &
exit 0
```

When I run the script and do

```
ps ax | grep myservice
```

I have three processes running:

```
4311 su root -c python myservice.py start
4421 /bin/bash -c python myservice.py start
4456 python myservice.py start
```

I was wondering why there are three processes that are created?

When I change my script as follows:

```
COMMAND="python myservice.py start"
su root -c "/bin/bash -c \"$COMMAND"\" & " &
```

I get two processes running:

```
5121 /bin/bash -c python myservice.py start
4793 python myservice.py start
```

I was under the impression appending & for the first su command will kill the process once the command is run. I am not sure where /bin/bash -c python myservice.py start process is created.

Is there anyway I can bring the processes running to one? Also how do I change the process name so that it looks something like as follows:

```
 4793 myservice
```

as opposed to

```
 4793 python myservice.py start
```

as it is right now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first scenario, I assume it is clear why the `su` and `python` processes exist, and you are unclear why the `bash` process exists.  From the `su` manpage:

> ```
>    -c, --command COMMAND
>        Specify a command that will be invoked by the shell using its -c.
> ```

The simple answer is that this bash shell process is started simply because the documentation says it will be.  However, I suspect the reason for this is to allow you to pass complex commands to `su` (e.g. including pipes, redirections, shell-builtins, etc).

It would be possible for `su` to fork and simply call the `execve()` system call for a given program path and arguments, but a lot of shell functionality would lost if that were the case - or you'd have to explicitly call `su root -c "/bin/bash -c <non-trivial command>"`

---

In your second scenario, the following happens:

- `su` starts and is put in the background
- `su` starts a `bash` process and puts it in the background
- `bash` starts a `python` process
- the `su` process has likely finished any cleanup by this point and exits (almost instantaneously to human observation)
- You then run `ps`, and observe the `bash` and `python` processes still running

---

If you wish to see just the `python` process running, then all you need to do is make sure the `&` control operator is within the quoted command passed to `su`:

```
su root -c "$COMMAND &"
```

Answer (score 0):

This call:

```
su root -c "$COMMAND" &
```

puts the `su` command in the background.  I don't know what is in your python script, but if you have it running in a loop, that means the su that you put in the background will NOT return until the command you passed returns.  I'm assuming since you pass `start` to your script it may be running as a daemon process that doesn't immediately return.

You have three processes because the su doesn't exit while your python continues to run.

The second one works as intended because you background the command that was passed to `su` so it immediately returns back to the `su`, so then the backgrounded `su` can return.  Also, you don't need the exit.